# How to track when a user views a JIRA issue

Tags: jira-plugin

In my plugin I need to track when a user views an issue using UI. Ideally I'd like to know if it was opened directly, or was viewed in Issue Navigator Detail View. I need to track who and when viewed an issue.

What's the best way to do this?

Cheers,
Oles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to use a [Servlet Filter](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview/jira-plugin-module-types/servlet-filter-plugin-module) plugin module and scan the requested URL for those corresponding to issue views. You can generally distinguish between viewing the issue directly and a view from within the Issue Navigator by examining the query parameters.

Alternatively, you could also build a [Web Panel](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview/jira-plugin-module-types/web-panel-plugin-module) plugin module that renders no significant UI, but which would always be invoked when an issue is viewed. You'd probably want to position the web-panel on the [right side of the issue view](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/web-fragments/view-issue-page-locations) with `atl.jira.view.issue.right.context`.

In either scenario above, you can fetch the current user from an injected [JiraAuthenticationContext](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/security/JiraAuthenticationContext.html).